# How to align a title with an subscript below of it

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, alignment, subscripts

Right now, I have this code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[top = 2.54cm, bottom = 2.54cm, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm]{geometry}   % en mecanica dejarlo en 2.54x2 y 2.1x2

\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}


    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    }


\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        {\scshape\large Some text book} 
        \\ \vspace{0.2cm}
        %

        {\scshape\Huge Algebra and Calculus} \\
        {\small\hspace{11.5cm} $^{\displaystyle\text{\textit{by} Peluche!}}$}

    \end{center}
    This is just some text without indent to let you see the width of the page.
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

that produces

[image]

where **Algebra and Calculus** is the title and **by Peluche!** the author of the document. This is a code I wrote a long time ago. To every "text book" I have to change the `\hspace` to make it aligned with the title of the "text book". But now, I'd like to align it automatically for every "text book". To try to do this, I wrote the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[top = 2.54cm, bottom = 2.54cm, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm]{geometry}   % en mecanica dejarlo en 2.54x2 y 2.1x2

\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}


    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}


    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    }


\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        {\scshape\large Some text book} 
        \\ \vspace{0.2cm}
        %
        {\scshape\Huge $\text{Algebra and Calculus}_{\text{\normalfont\small \textit{by} Peluche!}}$}

    \end{center}
    This is just some text without indent to let you see the width of the page.
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

that produces

[image]

The problem here is the not-alignment of the title to the center of the page because of the subscript "by Peluche!".

The question is how to center the title and how to positionate/align (automatically) the author's name at/with the end of the title. In others words, how to choose the argument of the `\hspace` in the first code automatically. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your question isn't entirely clear, what you after.
- Don't write title in math environment.
- Does author should be written as title subscript or as it is usulat at books centered below of the book title?
- In the first case you can center title by writing `subscript` by use of the `rlap` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[vmargin = 2.54cm, hmargin = 1.5cm]{geometry}   % en mecanica dejarlo en 2.54x2 y 2.1x2+
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
\scshape\large Some text book\

\medskip
        %
\scshape\Huge Algebra and Calculus\rlap{\textsubscript{\small\textit{by Peluche!}}}

    \end{center}
\lipsum[66]
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need with `\text` in math mode, `\textsubscript` is okay. And you can use `\phantom` to fill the left of title.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\xxxx}{\normalfont\small\textit{by} Peluche!}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{\scshape\large Some text book}
\\\vspace{0.2cm}
{\textsubscript{\phantom{\xxxx}}{\scshape\Huge Algebra and Calculus}\textsubscript{\xxxx}}
\end{center}
This is just some text without indent to let you see the width of the page.
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]